# Animating the transformation of a probability support

Tags: probability-or-statistics, regions, animation, coordinate-transformation

I'm trying to visualize how a transformation changes the support of a pdf. My problem is as follows:

Let X and Y be random variables with a joint pdf defined on the support `0 <= X <= Y <= 1` and consider the transformation `U = X/Y, V = Y`

The original support:

```
Rxy = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= y <= 1, {x, y}];
RegionPlot[Rxy, Mesh -> 15]
```

[image: Ruxy]

The transformed support looks like a unit square:

```
Ruv = TransformedRegion[Rxy, {Indexed[#, 1]/Indexed[#, 2],Indexed[#, 2]} &];
RegionPlot[Ruv, Mesh -> 15]
```

[image: Ruv]

Would anyone have suggestions on how to animate this transformation? I am aware of the [Animate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html) command. I also found this [article](http://rsdavis.mycpanel.princeton.edu/wp/?p=73) on how to animate a Conformal mapping, but was unable to apply its methods to my region.

For further clarification, I'm looking for something like this:

[image: transformation animation]

I want to visualize how the first region "morphs" into the second given the above transformation.

Comment: What would animate?

Comment: Hi wolfies,

It would animate exactly how the first region gets morphed into the second. For example: https://media.giphy.com/media/xT1R9RaJf4082UJyzC/giphy.gif

Comment: Would you mind mentioning where you got the animation from?

Comment: Please add the code to your post so that it can be copied and pasted.

Comment: I don't see that there is any partial 'morphing' of the one into the other, in any mathematical sense. Perhaps what you are seeking should be done in an animation package or Photoshop etc --- I don't see the maths of it though.

Comment: @J.M. The animation came from the article I referenced and hyperlinked in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to parameterize the problem a bit differently, but I was able to create the animation I wanted:

```
ParametricPlot[{t, m*t}, {m, 1, 100}, {t, 0, 1/m}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

Ideally I would let `m -> Infinity` but `m = 100` works well enough. This essentially generates a region consisting of lines with slope `m > 1`.

[image: Rxy]

Thus `X = t` and `Y = m*t`. When we make the transformation from `U` to `V` we get `U = X/Y = t/(m*t) = 1/m` and `V = Y = m*t`:

```
u[t_, m_] := 1/m;
v[t_, m_] := m*t;
ParametricPlot[{u[t, m], v[t, m]}, {m, 1, 100}, {t, 0, 1/m},PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image: Ruv]

Finally, the transformation can be animated with:

```
Animate[ParametricPlot[{t (1 - eps) + eps*u[t, m], m*t (1 - eps) + eps*v[t, m]},
{m, 1, 100}, {t, 0, 1/m}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
MeshStyle -> {Red, Blue}, Mesh -> 50, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #2 &},
MeshShading -> {{None, Automatic}, {Automatic, None}}], {eps, 0, 1}]
```

[image: animation]

This shows me how the support actually gets stretched under the transformation of `U` and `V`. You can also see this from the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant). It's like a Venetian blind when you only pull one string all the way down!